# Xcode Application sandbox folder doesn't show

Tags: xcode

I have Mac OS 10.7.3, with Xcode 4.3 , I am not able to see iPhone simulator folder in Application Support folder on MACINTOSH HD drive.

MACINTOSH HD/Library/Application Support/

There is no Library folder in User directory either.
Please help Let me know the solution.

Thanks

Comment: /Users/'you'/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0
or you can check  `NSLog(@"%@", [NSBundle mainBundle]);`

Answer (score 3):

The Simulator is stored in `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator`

To see the Library Folder in your user directory you need to choose the Go menu in finder, then hold down the option key on your keyboard and then choose Library, because Apple has hidden it in Lion.

You can also go to the Finder and use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>G</kbd>. Paste ~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator into the dialog box and click Go.